# Flutter - how to convert response to excel after that download it

Tags: excel, flutter, dart

I am beginner in flutter,i have need convert my response data to excel & after that i can download it. I am already use this package to convert my response data to excel https://pub.dev/packages/excel/versions/2.0.0-null-safety-3, but the problem i dont know how to download it to my device/emulator device.

**here my try implementation**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:excel/excel.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

...

void _Download() async {
final status = await Permission.storage.request();

if (status.isGranted) {
  var excel = Excel.createExcel();
  Sheet sheetObject = excel['sheet1'];

  CellStyle cellStyle = CellStyle(
      backgroundColorHex: "#1AFF1A",
      fontFamily: getFontFamily(FontFamily.Calibri));

  cellStyle.underline = Underline.Single; // or Underline.Double

  var cell = sheetObject.cell(CellIndex.indexByString("A1"));
  cell.value = 8; // dynamic values support provided;
  cell.cellStyle = cellStyle;

  // printing cell-type
  print("CellType: " + cell.cellType.toString());

  ///
  /// Inserting and removing column and rows

  // insert column at index = 8
  sheetObject.insertColumn(8);

  // remove column at index = 18
  sheetObject.removeColumn(18);

  // insert row at index = 82
  sheetObject.insertRow(82);

  // remove row at index = 80
  sheetObject.removeRow(80);

  var fileBytes = excel.save();
  var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  File(directory.path + "/dongle.xlsx")
    ..createSync(recursive: true)
    ..writeAsBytesSync(fileBytes ?? []);
} else {
  print('no permission');
}
```

}

**output for directory.path**
/data/user/0/com.example.myproject/app_flutter

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/excel

Comment: @AnmolMishra i think i use same package, but i just use null safety versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy that file to the Download folder by that you can have that file in your download folder.

```
  File file =   File(directory.path + "/dongle.xlsx")
                   ..createSync(recursive: true)
                   ..writeAsBytesSync(fileBytes ?? []);
    file.copy('/storage/emulated/0/Download/dongle.xlsx')
```

Comment: is this a code or command in terminal?

Comment: no no just put it after where you have created the file. I have edited my answer please check that.

Comment: ok its works, but cannot open the file

Comment: Does your file at /data/user/0/com.example.myproject/app_flutter can open ?

Comment: ok finally its work, thanks bro